# localStorage vs SQLite?

Tags: java, sqlite, html, gwt, local-storage

I'm building a Packaged App for Chrome. Looking into my database options, I'm curious if I understand the proper way of using these.

With SQLite, I'd create table `books` with the following rows `_id`, `title`, `category`, `date`, `price`, `qty_sold`.

With localStorage, I'd create table `_id` with key/pair such as `1`, `x499faj4`. Then I'd create table `title` with key/pair `x499faj4`, `book title`. Table `category`, with `x499faj4`, `fiction`.

I'm not sure if that makes sense. localStorage seems easier to implement but how would I then go about sorting those things to populate a list by category, price or quantity sold for example? Does localStorage make sense in this situation and am I using it properly? Any further suggestions? thanks

Answer (score 3):

`localStorage` is strictly a key/value store, so any kind of aggregation, sorting, filtering will all have to be in your own application code. `SQLite` is just that, a pretty robust SQL based storage engine, complete with sorting, filtering, etc.

SQLite while a little more complex to setup and get started will probably be extremely more robust in the long run.